# worst case analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice, pspice

I am trying to a worst case/monte carlo analysis of the following circuit. How do I proceed with ? I have Altium and PSPICE(the textual one and not schematic capture).
[image: Schematic]
The main components I want to derate is the bypass/decoupling filter in the Vin and the SHDN resistor.

My supply is all dc. In pspice I understand that there are .WC and .STEP commands that can do the worst case analysis and a step ranging of a particular componenet(in this case the voltage divider in the SHDN pin). 
The resistors (R58 and R60) will have a tolerance(its random of 1%) and also a TCR (in ppm/C) as well. How do I proceed with this

The PSPICE code is as stated below -

**Vin 1 0 32
c119 1 0 56pF
c122 3 0 56pF
c118 3 0 56pF
c123 0 0 56pF
c15 3 0 2.2uF
c11 3 0 47uF
r8 3 5 Ramod 133K
r9 5 0 Rbmod 12k
.model Ramod res(tc1 = 500)
.model Rbmod res(tc1 = 500)
.MC 50 DC V(5) YMAX LIST OUTPUT ALL 
.STEP Res Rbmod(R) 11K 13K 500
.probe
.end**

But the voltage in the node 5 which is the one for the SHDN pin shows 0.
C119,C122,C118 and C123 are not shown in the fig(but they are in parallel to C15 and C11).

Comment: As far as I can see, your circuit is just a divider with 2 resistors as far as DC analysis is concerned. This is easier to do with a calculator. I quite often use excel for doing DC Monte Carlo. I am not sure about Pspice, but I would check if it takes temco into account when doing Monte Carlo. Also if you are dealing with flat chip thick film resistors then life drift is often bigger than initial tol or tempco.

Comment: Which make and model of pspice (there are many)? Have you done a google search? Most spice packages support monte carlo analysis. Have you tried LtSpice? It's free and good and has great community support.

Comment: I am using orcad pslice. I don't want to use ltspice.